# When I realloc a buffer to be smaller, does it delete the data in the buffer until it reach the correct size?

Tags: c, realloc

My question is a little confusing, but what I'm asking is what does `realloc` do with the left over data when it minimizes it buffer? For example, lets just say I had a buffer filled with 50-bytes (assuming my buffer can hold up to 50-bytes of data). Later on in my code I resize my buffer with `realloc` to now only hold up to 30-bytes. What does `realloc` do with the left over 20-bytes?

Comment: wouldn't that be implementation dependent? if there's no memory pressure the logical thing to do would be do nothing except change the max size of the buffer.

Comment: Im not to sure im a beginner in c so I don't know all the mechanics to c yet.

Comment: it was more of  a rhetorical question.

Comment: I understand the logical thing to do is to increase it, but for some unknown reason i wanted to decrease it with realloc. The main reason im asking this question is to know if realloc a smaller size with junk left over would cause memory issue or possibly leave a security hole?

Comment: Typically that memory will be marked as unallocated and be available for future malloc calls from the same program

Comment: "*possibly leave a security hole*" if you want to *make sure* the data is *cleared*, then explicitly overwrite it yourself *before* shrinking the buffer by using `realloc()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`realloc` is exactly `malloc`+`memcpy`+`free`, except that sometimes it manages to do it in-place and the pointer it returns is numerically equal to the pointer you put in (but you can never rely on that). The left-over 20 bytes are freed.

From the C standard, `7.22.3.5` The realloc function

> The `realloc` function deallocates the old object pointed to by `ptr` and returns a pointer to a new object that has the size specified by `size`. The contents of the new object shall be the same as that of the old object prior to deallocation, up to the lesser of the new and old  sizes. Any bytes in the new object beyond the size of the old object have indeterminate values.

see also http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc or http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realloc.html

Comment: @FumerianGaming There is no need to write thank you here, though I understand the urge.  If you like an answer just upvote and if it is the solution to your problem then you should mark it as the correct answer.